# what redirect do i use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google, seo

I have a hosted rails application that gives every account a sub domain eg company.hosted_site.com

I have pointed our customers own domain to their subdomain via a A record and a cname so it looks like their own site.

But now i have 2 versions of the same site running so i need to now redirect the subdomain to the customers own domain.

My question is what redirect is best for this for SEO ?

thank you
Rick

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can use. First, assuming you have signed the domain up for Google Webmaster tools, you can select the prefered version of the URL. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

I would also add an HTACCESS rule to redirect visitors to the preferred URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} company.hosted_site.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hosted_site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: +1 Using .htaccess is usually a bit better for the server, because it goes through Apache without having to process any of the RoR code.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you get 301 site moved permanently, you'll be fine, doesn't matter which method you use to redirect, you just need to make sure to set the code properly.

Comment: It's correct to use 301, but I think it _does_ matter which method you use. HTML or JavaScript redirects can be disabled on the client side. Using Apache, either by .htaccess or in the httpd.conf usually gives the best results.

Answer (score 0):

If a file/domain has has moved for good you should use a "301 Moved Permanently"